# How to store enum type as lowercase string?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, enums, persistence

My model class (piece):

```java
public class User ... {

    @Enumerated(STRING)
    private Status status;

    ...

    public enum Status {

        ACTIVE,
        INACTIVE;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return this.name().toLowerCase();
        }
    }

    ...

    public String getStatus() {
        return status.name().toLowerCase();
    }

    public void setStatus(Status status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

As you see above I override toString method, but no effect.
Enumeration store in database as `ACTIVE` or `INACTIVE`.

P.S. I use hibernate jpa

Thanks for help!

P.S.S. I ask because I write REST service that produces json (in json object better use lower case, if I'm not mistake)

Comment: Your code works for me. `toString` and `getStatus` both returns lowercase strings. Are you sure you are not calling `name()` when constructing the json?

Comment: @Bittenus, I try to store enum in the database as lowercase string.

Comment: 1. Are you using a library to parse the enum or are you parsing it your self? 2. Is the code, that parses the enum for the database, using `name()` or `toString`?

Comment: I use next libraries: spring-orm, hibernate-core and hibernate-entitymanager

Comment: the accepted answer is the only way. It's a pity, Spring should use enum getters and setters by default if no converter defined

Answer (score 15, accepted):

write a `converter` class, annotated with `@Converter` , which implements `javax.persistence.AttributeConverter<YourEnum, String>`. There are two methods:

```
public String convertToDatabaseColumn(YourEnum attribute){..}
public YourEnum convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {..}
```

there you can apply your upper/lower case logic.

Later you can annotated your field, for using the given converter.

Comment: Thank you, Kent. That helped me. Just to complete, because I had to search for it: Annotating the field to use the converter works like this:
`@Colum`
`@Convert(converter=YourEnumConverter.class)`

Comment: @Buka right! Also, note that you should remove `@Enumerated` if you use `@Convert`, otherwise converter is ignored

Answer (score 9):

Here's a quick and practical example of using [`AttributeConverter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/AttributeConverter.html) <sup>(introduced in JPA 2.1)</sup>

Update your enum class:

```
public enum Status {
    ACTIVE,
    INACTIVE;

    public String toDbValue() {
        return this.name().toLowerCase();
    }

    public static Status from(String status) {
        // Note: error if null, error if not "ACTIVE" nor "INACTIVE"
        return Status.valueOf(status.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

Create attribute converter:

```
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;

@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class StatusConverter implements AttributeConverter<Status, String> {
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Status status) {
        return status.toDbValue();
    }

    @Override
    public Status convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        return Status.from(dbData);
    }
}
```

If `autoApply` is set to true, you don't need to add the `javax.persistence.Convert` annotation to all attributes that shall be converted. Otherwise, apply the converter:

```
import javax.persistence.Convert;
import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
public class User {

    @Convert(converter = StatusConverter.class)
    @Enumerated(STRING)
    private Status status;

    // ... other fields, constructor(s), standard accessors
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Jackson for the REST service let Jackson do the conversion at the REST boundary. Your question doesn't state a requirement for the DB to store lower case or for the application to process lower case.

```
public enum Status {
    STARTED,
    CONSUMING,
    GENERATING,
    FAILED,
    COMPLETED,
    DELETED;

    /**
     * Serialises to and from lower case for jackson.
     *
     * @return lower case Status name.
     */
    @JsonValue
    public String toLower() {
        return this.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Best practice is to use the upper-case for enum constants.

I see two options

1. Use lower-case in enum (not a good practice)
2. Change the getter method (getStatus method) of the bean using this enum to return lower case. (best possible option)

Comment: In the getter method I return Status enumeration. I change return type to String and change implementation to return status.name().toLowerCase(), but still no effect. Sorry